# List all file, but not directories, recursively in BASh

Tags: bash

I was wondering if there was a way to list all files from the current directory, but not the directories themselves, recursively in BASh.

EXAMPLE:

```
# list -r
/root/foo.txt
/root/log.txt
/root/tremp/passwd.list
```

But not:

```
# list -r
/root/
/root/foo.txt
/root/log.txt
/root/temp/
/root/tremp/passwd.list
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find . -type f
```

This will recursively search all files in the current directory. For instance:

```
$ mkdir temp
$ touch temp/passwd.list
$ touch log.txt
$ touch foo.txt
$ find . -type f
./foo.txt
./log.txt
./temp/passwd.list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `grep` the provided output with this:

```
grep -v ./$
```

That is, list everything but the lines which finish with "/" (directory)